# Need Haar Casscades for Nose, Eyes & Lips(Mouth)

Tags: opencv, face-detection, emgucv, emotion

I need Haar Cascades xml files for Mouth, Eyes & Nose. Do provide me useful links.

Comment: ^there is also cascade xml file for profile faces for those interested

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Look at this page: http://alereimondo.no-ip.org/OpenCV/34

There are haar cascades for eyes, nose and mouth :)

Comment: Thanks buddy, it's working well for the mouth, but the one for the nose is not working, do you have any other links?

Comment: Try this one: ftp://mozart.dis.ulpgc.es/pub/Software/HaarClassifiers/FaceFeaturesDetectors.zip It's a set of haar cascades for face features.

Comment: @dom links is now dead. any update since 2012 ? Is still haar adaboost approach  still best one for facial detection ? I m interested in skin

Answer (score 2):

I believe they are in the EmguCV package when you download it.  Get the emgucv zip file then they're in `.\opencv\data`.

I imagine you can get these straight from their SVN as well

Comment: Thnx buddy....bt d given xml files in d package r for d frontalface detection & eye..but I need Haar Cascade file for detecting Lips & Nose frm d detected face. Is der ny Haar Cascade file 4 dis???

Comment: yes check this link :https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/data/haarcascades

Answer (score 1):

This will help. Contains all haar cascade for eye, face and nose:
https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/data/haarcascades

Comment: It does not contain haar cascade for nose.

Comment: Please search thoroughly, its has full face haar cascade.