# Where can I find haar cascades xml files?

Tags: opencv

I'm looking for a website to download haar cascades xml files from. It can be for any objects as long as its a properly working cascade.

Comment: You don't need any website: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11537585/where-can-i-find-haar-cascades-xml-files/67897482#67897482

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Go to the opencv folder and check the data folder. You'll find haar-cascades for eyes, face, ears, upper body...:)
And they do work properly.

Here's one site
http://alereimondo.no-ip.org/OpenCV/34/
Don't know if they work though.

Comment: thanks but this damn fortiguard blocks me for accessing that website, any other sites you know of?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015498/need-haar-casscades-for-nose-eyes-lipsmouth
The second comment, the download starts immediately. Did you check the opencv folder?

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking for other objects as well such dogs, cats,etc. Basically anything found in pictures

Comment: So, you need the whole world? :P
For dogs etc etc you'll have to create your own xml files i guess. People usually need/want face/ears/nose/lips etc.

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore. Moreover, answer by [electrodrel](http://stackoverflow.com/users/558222/electrodrel) refers to the [OpenCV GitHub repository](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/data/haarcascades), that is a more consistent reference.

Answer (score 17):

As the link in the previous answer seems to be dead, you can also try to download them from the OpenCV GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/data/haarcascades)

Answer (score 11):

If you're using opencv from python, you can use this code snippet to use the built-in haar cascades:

```py
import os
import cv2

cv2_base_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(cv2.__file__))
haar_model = os.path.join(cv2_base_dir, 'data/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
```

Comment: There is no data folder in the site-packages any more

Comment: @MohsenSichani i used the python code to find the cv2 route and i did indeed find them on the data folder

Comment: ended up using cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11537585/where-can-i-find-haar-cascades-xml-files/67897482#67897482

Answer (score 4):

Wherever you have cloned the `opencv-contrib` (if you have made it from source) follow this path afterward and in OpenCV3.1.0 I have these for `Python` in `Ubuntu16` :

```
mona@mona:~/computer_vision/face_detection/opencv_contrib/modules/face/data/cascades$ ls
haarcascade_mcs_eyepair_big.xml    haarcascade_mcs_nose.xml
haarcascade_mcs_eyepair_small.xml  haarcascade_mcs_rightear.xml
haarcascade_mcs_leftear.xml        haarcascade_mcs_righteye_alt.xml
haarcascade_mcs_lefteye_alt.xml    haarcascade_mcs_righteye.xml
haarcascade_mcs_lefteye.xml        haarcascade_mcs_upperbody.xml
haarcascade_mcs_mouth.xml
```

Answer (score 4):

In the official repo of openCV in the `data` folder: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/data

Remember: Not everyone uses latest version of openCV therefore you can choose the version of the library through tags in the git repo.

Comment: These cascades seem to be somewhat timeless: e.g. this one https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opencv/opencv/master/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml is 5 years old as of now.

Comment: Thankyou so much, got the all models.

Answer (score 3):

The xml files can be accessed directly from cv2 like so

```py
cv2.data.haarcascades
```

heres a more detialed example

```py
face_cascade_name = cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml'
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier()
if not face_cascade.load(cv2.samples.findFile(face_cascade_name)):
    print("Error loading xml file")
    exit(0)
```

Comment: Tnx. Easiest answer

Answer (score 2):

in the opencv 3.1 you can find

C:\opencv3\data\lbpcascades

C:\opencv3\data\haarcascades_cuda

C:\opencv3\opencv_contrib-master\modules\face\data\cascades

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to go to other websites to find the cascade classifier files. you just need to go to the opencv releases site. There download the appropriate release. then open the downloaded file. In there   direct as followed : sources > data > haarcascades ; In that file you should find the all default haarcascade files.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the direct link to download haar-cascade-files from github link:-

https://github.com/anaustinbeing/haar-cascade-files

Just, clone or download as zip to get all the haar cascade xml files

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it with [git v2.25.0](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.25.0.txt), also tested with v2.26.2. This trick doesn't work with v2.30.1

#### TLDR

```sh
git clone --no-checkout --filter=tree:0 https://github.com/opencv/opencv
cd opencv

# requires git 2.25.x to 2.26.2
git sparse-checkout set data/haarcascades
```

You can use [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/get-docker/) to avoid installing a specific version of git

```sh
git clone --no-checkout --filter=tree:0 https://github.com/opencv/opencv
cd opencv

# requires git 2.25.x to 2.26.2
docker run --rm -it -v $PWD/:/code/ --workdir=/code/ alpine/git:v2.26.2 sparse-checkout set data/haarcascades
```

### Full solution

```sh
# bare minimum clone of opencv
$ git clone --no-checkout --filter=tree:0 https://github.com/opencv/opencv
...
Resolving deltas: 100% (529/529), done.

# Downloaded only ~7.3MB , takes ~3 seconds
# du = disk usage, -s = summary, -h = human-readable
$ du -sh opencv
7.3M    opencv/

# Set target dir
$ cd opencv
$ git sparse-checkout set data/haarcascades
...
Updating files: 100% (17/17), done.
# Takes ~10 seconds, depending on your specs

# View downloaded files
$ du -sh data/haarcascades/
9.4M    data/haarcascades/
$ ls data/haarcascades/
haarcascade_eye.xml                      haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml      haarcascade_licence_plate_rus_16stages.xml  haarcascade_smile.xml
haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml      haarcascade_frontalface_alt_tree.xml  haarcascade_lowerbody.xml                   haarcascade_upperbody.xml
haarcascade_frontalcatface.xml           haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml   haarcascade_profileface.xml
haarcascade_frontalcatface_extended.xml  haarcascade_fullbody.xml              haarcascade_righteye_2splits.xml
haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml          haarcascade_lefteye_2splits.xml       haarcascade_russian_plate_number.xml
```

### References

- [git-sparse-checkout-blog](https://github.blog/2020-01-17-bring-your-monorepo-down-to-size-with-sparse-checkout/#sparse-checkout-and-partial-clones)
- [git-sparse-checkout-docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-sparse-checkout)
- [git-filter-props-docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list)