# Raspberry Pi 3 Python Facial Recognition opencv

Tags: python, c++, opencv, numpy, raspberry-pi3

I'm receiving a detectMultiScale error. I made sure to specify the full path of the file. I am aiming to progress to real-time object recognition and tracking.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/home/pi/opencv-3.1.0/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/home/pi/opencv-3.1.0/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_eye.xml')
face_cascade.load('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

img = cv2.imread('/home/pi/cam.jpg',1)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY,0)

faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    img = cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
    roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    roi_color = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
    for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
        cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey),(ex+ew+ey+eh),(0,255,0),2)

cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here is the error code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/face.py", line 11, in <module>
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
error: /home/pi/opencv-3.1.0/modules/objdetect/src/cascadedetect.cpp:1639: error: (-215) !empty() in function detectMultiScale
```

Comment: is the xml file present in that location in the code ? check that. And the third line after imports, why are you loading the file it is already read from the above line

Answer (score 0):

#### OpenCV way:

You need a file for the HAAR cascade parameters. Sometimes that needs to be downloaded and isn't provided by default. [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11537585/where-can-i-find-haar-cascades-xml-files)  might give you hints about where to find them.

#### "face recognition" module

[dlib](http://dlib.net/) is the defacto C++ library now for haar-cascade for face extraction.

The *face recognition* module in python wraps dlib and can handle both face detection and recognition.

https://pypi.org/project/face-recognition/