# face detection , not face detected

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, face-recognition

I am trying to do face detection but it does not detect any face.

this is the function I have created for face detection

```
def faceDetection(test_img):
     gray_img=cv2.cvtColor(test_img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
     face_haar_cascade=cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
     # haar classifier
     faces=face_haar_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray_img,scaleFactor=1.32,minNeighbors=5)

     return faces,gray_img
```

this is used in

```
test_img=cv2.imread('pic.png')
faces_detected,gray_img=fr.faceDetection(test_img)
print("faces_detected:",faces_detected)


for (x,y,w,h) in faces_detected:
    cv2.rectangle(test_img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),thickness=5)

resized_img=cv2.resize(test_img,(500,500))
cv2.imshow("face",resized_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows
```

but when I run this script it does not show any face detected
simply give output this

> faces_detected: ()

and no box around image

Comment: Are you sure you have downloaded [haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11537585/where-can-i-find-haar-cascades-xml-files) to the correct destination?

Comment: yes, from github page of OpenCV

Comment: this is the link https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml

Comment: Try reducing scaleFactor, it's pretty high. Try default value of 1.1

Comment: no, it doesn't work , it detect but not face by reducing scaleFactor

Comment: If tips from @Julian don't work either, provide `pic.png`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a different haar cascade. The default one is `haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml`

```
face_haar_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml')
```

Change the scale factor you use for the cascade. If that doesn't work you can also reduce also the number of neighbors to maybe 2.

```
faces = face_haar_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray_img, scaleFactor=1.1, minNeighbors=5);
```

Check the number of faces you found

```
print('Faces found: ', len(faces))
```